# AWS RoboMaker simulations + testing explained

Tags: simulation, simulator

I am trying to understand how [AWS RoboMaker and WorldForge](https://aws.amazon.com/robomaker/) work, and am having trouble "*seeing the forest through the trees,*" and might need someone to "explain it to me like I'm 5" (ELIF).

Do you:

- Write your robot's firmware (in any language/library/RTOS you choose) and upload it to AWS and run it through their simulations/tests/workbenches? **or...**
- Write your robot's firmware in Python (which seems to be the only language they currently support, at least in the examples I can find), use their Python libraries/modules for interacting with their WorldForge simulations, and upload your Python code to AWS and run it through their simulations/tests/workbenches; **or...**
- Something else completely different?

Thanks for any clear + succinct (good step-by-step examples would be amazing!) steering here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [take a look at their Getting started > Concepts section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/robomaker/latest/dg/gettingstarted-concepts.html), they mention

> A typical simulation might use Robot Operating System (ROS) with one container simulating the environment in Gazebo, and a second container simulating the robot.

As I discuss [in my answer to your other question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/23804/9720), your robot needs some way to interact with the virtual environment. By the way it's described above, Amazon is assuming you're going to have some network I/O that will bridge your robot to the simulated environment. The simulated environment would be what hosts your virtual robot, with all the virtual sensors and encoders, etc. The virtual environment would all be put on one docker container.

The robot (as described by Amazon in the quote above) would run on another docker container. Your robot runs on whatever software you choose to write, Python, C++, etc., and it communicates over that network I/O to the simulator, which will generate synthetic feedback based on whatever your virtual sensors are programmed to do.

Comment: Thanks @Chuck (+1) I will likely have more followup questions, but the first was is this: is AWS RoboMaker expects your robot to be able to run on a docker container, doesn't that preclude any _real_ production robotics that would be running on ARM hardware an using real-time OSes like RIOT-OS and the likes? I believe docker is only linux and x86/64 architecture, no? Thanks again so much!

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup - Yup, pretty much, unless you've got a hardware emulator as I suggest in the other answer. Otherwise you're going to have to either structure your software such that it's not hardware-dependent or keep a parallel code base that has replaced the hardware dependencies with your simulated hardware interface.

Comment: Thanks again (+1), so it sounds like AWS RoboMaker cannot be used for building anything that doesn't run on x86/64 architectures (like ARM), and it cannot be used for anything that needs to run on an RTOS. But say I am writing a robot with firmware that _will_ run on an x86 chip, and is OK with using some flavor of Linux (`alpine`, whatever). Maybe I'd write this firmware in C, C++ or even Python...

Comment: If my application fits this description, then doesn't AWS RoboMaker do what I asked about [in my other question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/23801/simulator-that-allows-your-to-test-your-real-firmware-inside-a-simulated-world)? Meaning, it sounds like it will allow me to receive my inputs from the network I/O bridge, that were generated by the simulated environment "running" my virtual robot, then respond to those inputs, and then send the output commands back over the network I/O bridge back to the simulated environment, no?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup - `If my application fits this description, then doesn't AWS RoboMaker do what I asked about in my other question?` Yes, that's the point of it haha. The issue it sounds like you may have though is splitting out the hardware dependencies from your project. Instead of sending a PWM signal to Pin9, which won't exist in a docker container (without a hardware emulator), your code should send the PWM signal to some kind of an abstracted motor driver, you can have motor driver different implementations, one that forwards to Pin9, one that forwards to ROS or another network protocol.